# How can I get a transformed Stream<List<Object>> to display data with asynchronous code?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble getting a stream with a list of objects to populate in a ViewModel.

1. Load an asynchronous `Stream<List<Habit>>` from a Firestore Service
   in a `DailyViewModel`.
2. Call a transform method to turn that stream into a `Stream<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>>` that looks at a specific
   instance of each of my habits for today, and creates that instance if one doesn't exist. There are a few component pieces to this:

   1. For each habit in the initial stream, run a private method that checks if there is an instance of the habit for today, and initializes one if not. This is an asynchronous method because it calls back to the database to update the habit with the new instance.
   2. Then find the instance for today, and return a `HabitCompletionViewModel` with the habit and today's instance.
   3. Map these to a list.
3. That new stream is set in a property in the `DailyViewModel` as `todaysHabits`.
4. `todaysHabits` is called as the stream in a `StreamBuilder` in the `DailyView` widget.

The issue I am running into is that I know a completion for today is being found.

I am very fuzzy on what can/should be called as asynchronous code, and whether I'm using correct async/async* return/yield statements in my code, especially since I am trying to kick this process off as part of my constructor function for the `DailyViewModel`. I've used a bunch of print comments and it seems like everything is running, but the `todaysHabits` in my ViewModel is always set to null, and the StreamBuilder doesn't return any items.

Is there anything off in my code that could be causing this?

The DailyViewModel has this todaysHabits property, which is loaded near the bottom of the constructor function:

```
  late Stream<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>> todaysHabits;

  DailyViewModel({required WeekDates week}) {
    _log.v('initializing the daily viewmodel');
    _week = week;

    _habitService
      .loadActiveHabitsByUser(_loginAndUserService.loggedInUser!.id!)
        .then(
      (activeUserHabits) {
        todaysHabits = _getTodaysHabits(activeUserHabits);
        _log.v('todaysHabits has a length of ${todaysHabits.length}');
      },
    );
    setBusy(false);
  }
```

That constructor calls this _getTodaysHabits function which is supposed to convert that `Stream<List<Habit>>` into a `Stream<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>>`:

```
  Stream<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>> _getTodaysHabits(
      Stream<List<Habit>> habitsStream) {
    return habitsStream.asyncMap((habitsList) {
      return Stream.fromIterable(habitsList).asyncMap(
        (habit) async {
          await _updateHabitWithNewCompletions(habit);
          HabitCompletion completion = habit.completions!.firstWhere(
              (completion) => completion.date
                  .dayEqualityCheck(DateTime.now().startOfDate()));
          return HabitCompletionViewModel(completion: completion, habit: habit);
        },
      ).toList();
    });
  }
```

And my view (which is used the Stacked package to display the contents of the ViewModel and update accordingly) contains this StreamBuilder that should be returning a list of tiles for each `HabitCompletionViewModel`:

```
            StreamBuilder<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>>(
                stream: vm.todaysHabits,
                builder: ((context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                    return Center(child: Text('No Habits Found'));
                  } else {
                    return Column(children: [
                      ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) => HabitCompletionTile(
                          key: ValueKey(snapshot.data![i].habit.id),
                          vm: snapshot.data![i],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]);
                  }
                })),
```

Comment: what's the reason for using `Stream.fromIterable` ?

Comment: I was having a different issue with this earlier, and added `fromIterable` as a result of the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111075/mapping-a-streamlist-to-another-type-is-returning-a-streamnull/74114917#74114917

Comment: Are you getting a `LateInitializationError` on `todaysHabits`? You must initialize a `late` variable prior to accessing it. It looks like you are accessing `todaysHabbits` (which is a `late` variable) and passing it to the `StreamBuilder` when there is no guarantee that it has been initialized yet.

Comment: use `Future.wait` then, something like: `myListMapper(List list) async {
  print('myListMapper start: $list');
  final futures = list.map((e) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => e * 10));
  final transformed = await Future.wait(futures);
  print('myListMapper end: $transformed');
  return transformed;
}

Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (i) => [i, i+1, i+2])
  .take(4)
  .asyncMap(myListMapper)
  .listen((e) => print('listened: $e'));` the same here: https://pastebin.com/3tKA2h1n

Answer (score 0):

Based on pskink's comment, I made the following updates that seem to work. (There is a slight lag when I switch to that view), but it is now showing the correct data.

Basically seems like the issue was that my previous code was returning a list of futures, instead of just a list of HabitCompletionViewModels, and using Future.wait waits for all those to complete.

Pulled out the mapping from List to List into a separate sub-method (here is the main method):

```
  Stream<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>> _getTodaysHabits(
      Stream<List<Habit>> habitsStream) {
    return habitsStream.asyncMap(
        (habitsList) async => await _mapHabitsToViewModel(habitsList));
  }
```

Updated that sub-method so it first returns a List<Future>, and then uses Future.wait to wait for those to complete as HabitCompletionViewModels before returning that new list:

```
  Future<List<HabitCompletionViewModel>> _mapHabitsToViewModel(
      List<Habit> habitsList) async {
    List<Future<HabitCompletionViewModel>> newList =
        habitsList.map((habit) async {
      HabitCompletion completion = habit.completions!.firstWhere((completion) =>
          completion.date.dayEqualityCheck(DateTime.now().startOfDate()));
      return HabitCompletionViewModel(completion: completion, habit: habit);
    }).toList();
    List<HabitCompletionViewModel> transformed = await Future.wait(newList);
    return transformed;
  }
```

Comment: if you don need to access `transformed` (I had to print it) then you don't have to `await Future.wait(...` - just `return Future.wait(newList);`, also `newList` does not have to be a `List` so `.toList()` can be removed